# Cannot test PHP files on servers

Tags: php, linux, apache

i have a couple of servers running linux.

I installed httpd and **PHP** on **CentOS** **7** but everytime i type `192.168.10.83/info.php` in web-browser to test `phpinfo();` i see nothing...

Then i compiled **apache** and **php** on my local **PowerPC** machine and the same things happen.. what should i do? do i need to configure **httpd.conf**? every php file i open from browsers dont run...

Thanks

Comment: type 192.168.10.83 only, what do you see?

Comment: I see my index.html file, i added some test input code

Comment: can you provide us with your code

Comment: If you have SSH access, run the following command: `service --status-all`. Check if PHP is actually running...

Comment: most likely php is not configured properly.

Comment: @DavidWilkinson httpd service is running correctly.. and i added module loading script to httpd.conf, libphp7.so is located in lib directory...

Comment: @steady_daddy i think that is the problem.. because when i used to test some php code.. last time i needed to add something to php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/lamp/lamp-on-centos-7) provides you with step by step instructions on setting up LAMP stack on CentOS 7. Go through it to make sure you haven't missed anything.

Comment: i have created /var/www/html/info.php but still i dont see nothing when i run 192.168.10.83/info.php

Comment: You have error in LAMP configuration most likely. Try this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-7

Comment: sorry, i skipped one step... thank you so much for poiting this tut for me :D ! phpinfo() is working now :)